# React.js state items array not updating properly even not showing any error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At first please see the picture for actually what's going on

[image]

The issue is while marked the checkbox then text erasing but I want to update a state field from state array & the functionalities are like below

```
state = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Buy milk', done: true },
        { id: 2, text: 'Deed cat', done: false },
        { id: 3, text: 'Wash floor', done: false }
    ]
};

markItemDone = (i) => {
    this.setState(state => {
        const items = state.items.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === i){
                return item.done = true;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        });

        return {
            items,
        };
    });
}
```

JSX:

```
 <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    onClick={() => this.markItemDone(item.id)}
    defaultChecked={item.done ? true : null}
 />
```

I'm not finding the actual solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you say `return item.done = true;`. This is returning a boolean instead of an item object and thus why you see `1: true` in your screenshot. Instead, you want something like this:

```
        if (item.id === i){
            return {
                ...item,
                done: true,
            };
        } else {
            return item;
        }
```

This will make a copy of the original item object, set its `done` field to be `true`, and return the new item.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your `map` callback:

```
return item.done = true;
```

will map `item` to `undefined` for the `item` where `id === i`. Try revising your `map` callback as shown:

```
const items = state.items.map((item) => {

    /* Return copy of item. If id === item.id, add done : true to 
        mapped result. For all other cases, ensure done is undefined */ 
        return { ...item, done : id === item.id ? true : undefined };

});
```

Comment: It'd probably be advisable not to mutate `item` directly here.

Comment: @JKillian agreed